# Make child div occupy entire parent space on resizing

Tags: css, html

I have a container `div` that has two element. On resizing one inner `div` moves under another.

But the requirement here is on resizing when one `div` moves under another the first `div` should take the entire width of the parent.

The real question has many div's . If you want you can also try with multiple. But find a common solution.

Here's the fiddle

[div fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFqaT/)

Here's by HTML and CSS

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class='inner'></div>
  <div class='inner'><div>
</div>
```

Try giving a CSS solution as I know the container can be snapped to adjust child div using css .

```
.cont {
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:100px;
}
.inner {
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    margin:4px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: "the real question has many div's" so in many condition when one div moves under, what should be the transformation to others?

Comment: others fit parent width equally distributed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with this a bit, and I was able to solve it with media queries. Check out the demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mFqaT/3/), and here is the code:

```
.cont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 435px) {
    .inner {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .cont {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still got some Idea. would be great if some one provide a 2+ solution also or ill post anotehr question ?

Comment: plese some one let me know do I need to post another question on this ?

Comment: Do you know how many `div` elements will be? Or it will be totally dynamic?

Answer (score -1):

You might try giving the containing div a display value of `table-cell`.

Check this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UdOPEDi/1/).

Comment: inner div does not fit to outer div's width

Comment: let me know if success

Comment: I'm wondering, does you height have to be fixed? Also by adding a media query, you can adjust elements based on the width of the browser. Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/UdOPEDi/3/

Comment: i have a number of divs actually but on resize the div start dissapearing and thats the requirement. But the appearing div needs to take up remaining space. we can do by jquery resize but a css solution if possible is preferrable .

Comment: I would probably go with the media query route then, to avoid unnecessary Js. Does this demo work for you? http://jsbin.com/UdOPEDi/4/ (Try resizing the browser, and check the css.)